# Webscraping table with multiple pages using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape this webpage https://www.whoscored.com/Statistics using BeautifulSoup in order to obtain all the information of the player statistics table. I'm having lot of difficulties and was wondering if anyone would be able to help me.

```
url = 'https://www.whoscored.com/Statistics'
html = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
text = [element.text for element in soup.find_all('div' {'id':"statistics-table-summary"})]
```

My problem lies in the fact that I don't know what the correct tag is to obtain that table. Also the table has several pages and I would like to scrape every single one. The only indication I've seen of a change of page in the table is the number in the code below:

```
<div id="statistics-table-summary" class="" data-fwsc="11">
```

Comment: +1 for improving the question. Seems possible the comment below holds and you will need a method like selenium. You can verify by print the soup and seeing if the info you want is there. With respect to the table. Right click inspect on the top of the actual table and find the actual table tag in the html. When you select that tag the table itself should become highlighted. You want the table, rather than the div above. The table has an id  of top-team-stats-summary-grid. You are probably better off asking one question for the table and a follow up for the different pages.

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me like that site loads their data in using Javascript. In order to grab the data, you'll have to mimic how a browser loads a page; the requests library isn't enough. I'd recommend taking a look at a tool like [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), which uses a "robotic browser" to load the page. After the page is loaded, you can then use BeautifulSoup to retrieve the data you need.

Here's a [link](https://realpython.com/modern-web-automation-with-python-and-selenium/) to a helpful tutorial from RealPython.

Good luck!